# Backbone Marionette Route to Server URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to add some client side validation that the user is signed in and if they aren't I want to route them to the signin page. The problem is that the signin page is outside of my Backbone Marionette app. Is there a way in Marionette, Backbone, jQuery or Javascript to route a user to a server side URL leaving the Marionette app?

So they'd go directly to localhost:3000/signin. I'm not sure how/if this is even possible to do with the Approuter but I'm assuming it isn't.

This is basically the pattern I'd like to follow (I'm using jQuery cookie to access cookies):

```
API =
    list: ->
      if $.cookie('user_id') != null
        console.log "continue to marionette"
      else 
        console.log "route to signin"
```

Do I need to have the signin portion also live in my Backbone Marionette app instead of outside of it as a Rails view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward to do. Just change the `window.location` to your desired redirect.

```
window.location = "/signin"
```